# Saving regression model in pySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

In pySpark MLlib there seems to be no way to save and load regression models, such as the LogisticRegressionModel, SVMModel, NaiveBayesModel and DecisionTreeModel.  There *is* load and save on the recommender model MatrixFactorizationModel through JavaSaveable and JavaLoader mixins, but the regression models are not done this way.

Is there a way that I could work around this by supplying my own load and save routines?  If so, how would I go about this?

Is this functionality expected in a future release, or is pySpark MLlib being phased out?

Answer (score 0):

In Spark 1.3.1, the `LinearModel` class, which is the base class for most of the linear classifiers (i.e. `LogisticRegressionModel`) is a pure Python class, so you can just try to pickle it or you can save the attributes `_coeff - weights()` and the `_intercept - intercept()` by yourself and the construct the `LogisticRegressionModel` class passing both the weights and the intercept term, like in the example below:

```
model = LogisticRegressionModel(weights, intercept)
```